# Customize Table Header

Tags: tables, tabulary

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{table}%[h]
\centering
\captionof{table}{\textbf{Descriptive Statistics on Some         
Variables}\\\small{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing             
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa 
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}&&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable A}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable B}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable C}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable D}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable E}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable F}\\\hline
Mean                &&0.43      &0.24   &0.32   &0.34   &0.32   &0.39\\
Median              &&0.89      &0.48   &0.22   &0.36   &0.15   &0.24\\
Standard Deviation  &&4.06      &1.31   &2.27   &1.46   &1.58   &3.57\\
Variance            &&17.22     &3.35   &5.17   &2.13   &3.33   &15.60\\
Kurtosis            &&1.22      &2.45   &5.37   &2.04   &4.93   &7.62\\
Skewness            &&-0.12     &-0.51  &0.57   &-0.06  &0.31   &-0.39\\
Range               &&30.33     &16.79  &21.18  &11.51  &16.50  &42.57\\
Minimum             &&-19.62    &-8.82  &-9.54  &-5.41  &-6.38  &-24.16\\
Maximum             &&11.11     &7.47   &11.64  &6.10   &9.22   &17.51\\
Count               &&326       &316    &321    &226    &426    &454\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

My problem is that I would like to center the table title, but leave the table description justified. I have tried various solutions such as \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} among others. Although, when I try to center the title, the table description does also become centred. Ideally, I hope to be able to make a table caption, which looks like this:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

[image]

code is similar as in [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) answer with differences:

- change table numbering to `\Roman`
- used `\caption` instead of `captionof`
- used `tabular*` table environment

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
                    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}%[h]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.2}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics on Some
Variables}

\parbox{\linewidth}{\small \lipsum[11]}

\medskip
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{5}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}
            & {Variable A} & {Variable B} & {Variable C}
            & {Variable D} & {Variable E} & {Variable F}        \\
\midrule
Mean        &   0.43 &  0.24 &  0.32 &  0.34 &  0.32 &  0.39    \\
Median      &   0.89 &  0.48 &  0.22 &  0.36 &  0.15 &  0.24    \\
Standard Deviation
            &   4.06 &  1.31 &  2.27 &  1.46 &  1.58 &  3.57    \\
Variance    &  17.22 &  3.35 &  5.17 &  2.13 &  3.33 &  15.60   \\
Kurtosis    &   1.22 &  2.45 &  5.37 &  2.04 &  4.93 &   7.62   \\
Skewness    &  -0.12 & -0.51 &  0.57 & -0.06 &  0.31 &  -0.39   \\
Range       &  30.33 & 16.79 & 21.18 & 11.51 & 16.50 &  42.57   \\
Minimum     & -19.62 & -8.82 & -9.54 & -5.41 & -6.38 & -24.16   \\
Maximum     &  11.11 &  7.47 & 11.64 &  6.10 &  9.22 &  17.51   \\
    \addlinespace
Count       & {326}  & {316} & {321} & {226} & {426} & {454}    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted to code in the first place. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `centering` option and a `\parbox` for the table description. In this case you should use the optional argument so the description doesn't appear in the list of tables.  I also improved the general look using the `S` column type from `siunitx`, to have numbers aligned on the decimal dot (except the last row):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}%[h]
\def\arraystretch{1.25}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=18mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\centering
\captionof{table}{\textbf{Descriptive Statistics on Some
Variables}\\[1ex]\parbox{\linewidth}{\small Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=-2.2]*{4}{S}S[table-format=-2.2]@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}&{Variable A} & {Variable B} & {Variable C} & {Variable D} & {Variable E} & {Variable F}\\
\midrule
Mean & 0.43 & 0.24 & 0.32 & 0.34 & 0.32 & 0.39 \\
Median & 0.89 & 0.48 & 0.22 & 0.36 & 0.15 & 0.24 \\
Standard Deviation & 4.06 & 1.31 & 2.27 & 1.46 & 1.58 & 3.57 \\
Variance & 17.22 & 3.35 & 5.17 & 2.13 & 3.33 & 15.60 \\
Kurtosis & 1.22 & 2.45 & 5.37 & 2.04 & 4.93 & 7.62 \\
Skewness & -0.12 & -0.51 & 0.57 & -0.06 & 0.31 & -0.39 \\
Range & 30.33 & 16.79 & 21.18 & 11.51 & 16.50 & 42.57 \\
Minimum & -19.62 & -8.82 & -9.54 & -5.41 & -6.38 & -24.16 \\
Maximum & 11.11 & 7.47 & 11.64 & 6.10 & 9.22 & 17.51 \\
\addlinespace
Count & {326} & {316} & {321} & {226} & {426} & {454} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! And thanks for the help on the coding of the table it self. You are far too kind.

Comment: @Andreas: It's a pleasure to help when I can, and it may be useful to others.